# Should I upgrade my Lightspeed Zulu 2 to a 3?

Tags: headset

I have a Zulu 2 from 2013. The cost of upgrading it to a Zulu 3 is 400$. Gets an extra 1-2 years of warranty.
What they do for the trade in is to replace the control module, cables with Kevlar cables and replace foam parts. Everything else stays the same.

Is it worth upgrading? Or should I just buy some sugru and fix the parts around the joints where the rubber molding is breaking apart?

Comment: Probably an opinion based question.

Comment: I don't believe there is any ANR performance increase, so you'd be doing it mostly to get the bluetooth feature.

Comment: I always measure the cost of this sort of thing on "Number of hours flying for my money".  That $400 might get me a couple hours flying and a burger on landing..... if ill get as much enjoyment as that out of a new headset, I'd go for it. otherwise I'd take the money and go for the burger!

Comment: @Jamiec Thank you for that comment. Everything works on the device. It's just the rubber parts near where the cords connect into the headset and control modules are falling apart. They will replace the cables with kevlar cables, replace the bluetooth module and send it back. Wondering if SUGRU is not a better option.

Answer (score 1):

It’s opinion based. That being said, I upgraded my Zulu 2 to Zulu 3 and love ‘em!